# JavaFX get elements from a Tab

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, javafx-8

```
package sample.GUI;

import sample.sampleThing;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Console  implements Initializable {
    public TextField messageOut = new TextField();
    public TextArea consoleOutput = new TextArea();
    public AnchorPane TabAnchorPane = new AnchorPane(messageOut, consoleOutput);
    public Tab tab = new Tab("Tab", TabAnchorPane);

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;
    SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = tabPane.getSelectionModel();

    String string1, string2;

    public Console() {
         super();
    }

    public Console(String str, String str2) {
        super();
        this.string1 = str;
        this.string2 = str2;
    }

    public void newTab(String str){
        Tab ntab = tab;
        tab.setText(str);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(ntab);
    }

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
        Tab tab1 = tab, tab2 = tab;
        tab1.setText(string1);
        tab2.setText(string2);
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);
    }

    public void clear() {
        Tab tmptb = selectionModel.getSelectedItem();

      //GUIUtils.runSafe(tmptb.consoleOutput::clear);
    }
```

Code from my GUI class (things renamed for secrecy about my project)
What I need help with is getting the consoleOutput && messageOut per tab
Specifically

```
node[] arr = getTab.getContent.getNodeArray //or something like that
for(node nd : arr) {
    if (nd == consoleOutput || nd == messageOut)
        //do much stuff
}
```

I could provide more info but I don't know what I should provide
the GUIUtils.runSafe is just a runnable taken from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52197/console-component-in-javafx
actually a bit of this code is based on what he has...

Comment: the tab has Tab.getContent(); it returns a node

Answer (score 1):

Tab to Node, Node to Parent, and parents usually have children:

```
((Parent) tab.getContent()).
    getChildrenUnmodifiable();
```